# Getting the original File/Image path after picking it using Flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I am developing a photo vault using Flutter. I need to list all the images in the mobile storage, and when the user picks one or more images. I need to move that image(s) into App Private. So that no other app can see it. So for moving the file, I need the location/path of the picked image(s). which no plugin on earth is providing.

Below is the list of plugins I tried. Each one of them provides the path of the image copied to the app private directory. No the original one

- [file_picker 2.1.6](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)
- [image_picker 0.6.7+22](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)
- [multi_image_picker 4.7.15](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker)

It would be a big help if you could suggestion some solution for it.

Thank You